# Disable write in innodb_log_file on inserts , AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS my innodb_log_file_size is very small (134mb) and it is  causing problems with inserts and over all with processing big amount of data (millions of records).
In AWS it is impossible to modify this parameter, is there a way to stop writing in it on Inserts?

Answer (score 1):

Writes to the Innodb redo log file are required. There is no way to use InnoDB without it.

It wasn't possible to resize the log file in the early days of Amazon RDS (I had a chat with the RDS product manager about that at an AWS conference), but a couple of years ago, they did eventually add support to resize it.

You have to restart the RDS instance after changing the log file size. It can't change the value on a running instance. This is also true of MySQL even when not using RDS.

Comment: I change it by doing next I create a new DB parameter group with required values and attach to my RDS apply changes and restart my RDS and it was updated

Answer (score 0):

I change **innodb_log_file_size** by doing next

> I create a new DB parameter group (copied existone) changed required values and attach it to
>   my RDS apply changes and restart my RDS and it was updated